# Problem removing whitespace from a string in r

Tags: r, string, gsub, stringr

I know this seems like a duplicate, but I have tried several solutions to this problem including this one, maybe I have a problem with my scraping that produces this problem

### Example

This is what I am trying to do:

I scraped this dataset from Wikipedia:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

Sueldos <- read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Salario_m%C3%ADnimo_en_Chile") %>% html_nodes(".wikitable") 

Sueldos <-rvest::html_table(Sueldos[[1]])

colnames(Sueldos) <- make.names(colnames(Sueldos))

Sueldos <- Sueldos %>% rename(Sueldo = Monto.bruto.enpesos.chilenos) %>% dplyr::select(Desde, Sueldo)
```

The dataset looks like this:

```
|Desde                   |Sueldo |
|:-----------------------|:------|
|1 de septiembre de 1987 |11 335 |
|1 de febrero de 1989    |15 488 |
|1 de junio de 1989      |18 000 |
|1 de junio de 1990      |26 000 |
|1 de junio de 1991      |33 000 |
|1 de junio de 1992      |38 600 |
|1 de junio de 1993      |46 000 |
|1 de junio de 1994      |52 150 |
|1 de junio de 1995      |58 900 |
|1 de junio de 1996      |65 500 |
```

I want to trim whitespace in Sueldos to turn them to numeric, usually, I have no problem trimming this whitespace, but several trials have given me the same result:

### Test 1

I first thought I would try with *str_remove_all* from *stringr*

```
Sueldos <- Sueldos %>%  str_remove_all(Sueldo, pattern = " ")
```

But it didn't change

### Test 2

Then I thought of using *str_replace_all*

```
Sueldos <- Sueldos %>%  mutate(Sueldo = str_replace_all(Sueldo, pattern = " ", replacement = ""))
```

And nothing

### Test 3

I thought maybe as in the link above if I used *fixed* it would work

```
Sueldos <- Sueldos %>%  mutate(Sueldo = str_replace_all(Sueldo, pattern = fixed(" "), replacement = ""))
```

Nothing

### Test 4

I finally tried gsub, just in case

```
Sueldos$Sueldo <- gsub(x =  Sueldos$Sueldo, pattern = " ", replacement = "")
```

Still nothing, I dont get what is going on

#### SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
  [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
  [1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.3     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.0     tibble_2.1.3   
  [8] ggplot2_3.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1 rvest_0.3.4     xml2_1.2.2     

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] tidyselect_0.2.5  xfun_0.10         haven_2.1.1       lattice_0.20-38   colorspace_1.4-1  vctrs_0.2.0       generics_0.0.2   
  [8] htmltools_0.4.0   yaml_2.2.0        rlang_0.4.1       pillar_1.4.2      glue_1.3.1        withr_2.1.2       selectr_0.4-1    
 [15] modelr_0.1.5      readxl_1.3.1      lifecycle_0.1.0   munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  htmlwidgets_1.5.1
 [22] evaluate_0.14     knitr_1.25        curl_4.2          highr_0.8         htmlTable_1.13.2  broom_0.5.2       Rcpp_1.0.2       
 [29] scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.5   checkmate_1.9.4   jsonlite_1.6      hms_0.5.1         digest_0.6.22     stringi_1.4.3    
 [36] grid_3.6.1        cli_1.1.0         tools_3.6.1       magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.2    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.3  
 [43] zeallot_0.1.0     lubridate_1.7.4   assertthat_0.2.1  rmarkdown_1.16    httr_1.4.1        rstudioapi_0.10   R6_2.4.0         
 [50] nlme_3.1-141      compiler_3.6.1
```

Comment: How about `trimws`? Although given that your previous attempts failed, I doubt this will work...but worth a try... Unless you want to remove all whitespaces (not only leading/trailing)

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, I do want to take out all whitespaces, since I want to transform that column into a numeric dataset

Comment: I can't reproduce your data set (proxy problems, etc.) Can you please share a reproducible example via `dput()`?

Comment: Is it possible it is an other character than white space you want to remove ?

Comment: Could be @cbo, I thought about that, but since it looks like whitespace, I don't know what character to use instead

Comment: Could you share your data with a `dput(Sueldos)` ?

Comment: If you want to remove whitespace and not just blanks,  use `\\s`

Comment: Use `Sueldos$Sueldo <- gsub("(*UCP)\\s+", "", Sueldos$Sueldo, perl=TRUE)` to remove all whitespace there is in Unicode table. If the text remains as it is, what you want to remove is not whitespace.

Comment: The space you want to eliminate is `intToUtf8(160)` (found via `utf8ToInt(Sueldos$Sueldo[1])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a whitespace has ascii 32, but when I look under that is the character in the column Sueldo, the character between the numbers has ascii 160. One solution i can offer is to replace the column using intToUtf8(160). As for what exactly is ascii score 160 in this data, I am not sure.

It might be called [non breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), as @WiktorStribiżew pointed out below, I am not sure about the distinction between this and white space.

```
sapply(unlist(strsplit(Sueldos$Sueldo[2],"")),utf8ToInt)
  1   1       3   3   5 
 49  49 160  51  51  53

utf8ToInt(" ")
[1] 32
```

Now if we gsub the correct character:

```
gsub(intToUtf8(160),"",Sueldos$Sueldo)

 [1] "11335"     "15488"     "18000"     "26000"     "33000"     "38600"    
 [7] "46000"     "52150"     "58900"     "65500"     "71400"     "80500"    
[13] "90500"     "100000"    "105500"    "111200"    "115648"    "120000"   
[19] "127500"    "135000"    "144000"    "159000"    "165000"    "172000"   
[25] "182000"    "193000"    "210000"    "225000"    "241000"    "250000"   
[31] "257500"    "264000"    "270000"    "276000"    "288000[1]" "301000[2]"
```

Comment: How come a non-breaking space is not whitespace?

Comment: I have no idea @WiktorStribiżew, I took the data and saw that it has ascii 160. And if you replace that, it works. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because a non-breaking space is whitespace. It is even called: non-breaking **space**.

Comment: Woe, @StupidWolf this actually works, I will choose your answer in a minute

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I always run into weird characters, and I check the ascii score to find out.

Comment: Weird stuff that someone downvoted your answer, I don't know why @StupidWolf

Answer (score 1):

The Answer of @StupidWolf worked for me, I wanted to add what my final code was just to keep the tidyverse format for whoever likes this better:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)


Sueldos <- read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Salario_m%C3%ADnimo_en_Chile") %>% html_nodes(".wikitable") 

Sueldos <-rvest::html_table(Sueldos[[1]])

colnames(Sueldos) <- make.names(colnames(Sueldos))

Sueldos <- Sueldos %>% rename(Sueldo = Monto.bruto.enpesos.chilenos) %>% dplyr::select(Desde, Sueldo) %>% mutate(Desde = lubridate::dmy(Desde), Sueldo = gsub(x = Sueldo, pattern = intToUtf8(160),replacement =   ""))
```

This works great

#### if you prefer stringr:

replace the last line of code with:

```
Sueldos <- Sueldos %>% rename(Sueldo = Monto.bruto.enpesos.chilenos) %>% dplyr::select(Desde, Sueldo) %>% mutate(Desde = lubridate::dmy(Desde), Sueldo = str_remove_all(Sueldo, pattern = intToUtf8(160)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use `str_replace_all` on a variable (and not the tibble) :

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rvest))

Sueldos <- read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Salario_m%C3%ADnimo_en_Chile") %>% html_nodes(".wikitable")

Sueldos <-rvest::html_table(Sueldos[[1]])

colnames(Sueldos) <- make.names(colnames(Sueldos))

Sueldos <- Sueldos %>% rename(Sueldo = Monto.bruto.enpesos.chilenos) %>% dplyr::select(Desde, Sueldo)

# test <- Sueldos$Desde[1]
# test %>%
#         stringr::str_remove_all(string = ., pattern = " ")

Sueldos %>%
        mutate(Desde = Desde %>% stringr::str_remove_all(string = ., pattern = " "))
#>                  Desde             Sueldo
#> 1  1deseptiembrede1987             11 335
#> 2     1defebrerode1989             15 488
#> 3       1dejuniode1989             18 000
#> 4       1dejuniode1990             26 000
#> 5       1dejuniode1991             33 000
#> 6       1dejuniode1992             38 600
#> 7       1dejuniode1993             46 000
#> 8       1dejuniode1994             52 150
#> 9       1dejuniode1995             58 900
#> 10      1dejuniode1996             65 500
#> 11      1dejuniode1997             71 400
#> 12      1dejuniode1998             80 500
#> 13      1dejuniode1999             90 500
#> 14      1dejuniode2000            100 000
#> 15      1dejuniode2001            105 500
#> 16      1dejuniode2002            111 200
#> 17      1dejuliode2003            115 648
#> 18      1dejuliode2004            120 000
#> 19      1dejuliode2005            127 500
#> 20      1dejuliode2006            135 000
#> 21      1dejuliode2007            144 000
#> 22      1dejuliode2008            159 000
#> 23      1dejuliode2009            165 000
#> 24      1dejuliode2010            172 000
#> 25      1dejuliode2011            182 000
#> 26      1dejuliode2012            193 000
#> 27     1deagostode2013            210 000
#> 28      1dejuliode2014            225 000
#> 29      1dejuliode2015            241 000
#> 30      1deenerode2016            250 000
#> 31      1dejuliode2016            257 500
#> 32      1deenerode2017            264 000
#> 33      1dejuliode2017            270 000
#> 34      1deenerode2018            276 000
#> 35 1deseptiembrede2018 288 000[1]<U+200B>
#> 36      1demarzode2019 301 000[2]<U+200B>
```

Comment: The result in this still has whitespace betreon the numbers, your solution got the whitespace out of the Desde, and not the sueldo variable

Answer (score 0):

Base R (regex) solution:

```
Sueldos$Sueldo <- gsub("\\s+", "", Sueldos$Sueldo)
```